# vQmod code syntax

Tags: opencart

I'm writing vqmod opencart modification and got one problem. There's a basic code:

```
<operation>
<search position="after"><![CDATA[<?php echo $description; ?></div></div>]]></search>
<add>
<![CDATA[<div class="content"><h2>Testimonials</h2><div class="box-testimonial"><?php echo $description_new; ?></div></div>]]>
</add>
</operation>
```

So What I want to do is to make some kind of conditional to display the code from  only when $description_new is not empty. What will be the syntax in this vqmode code?

Thanks in advance,
Arek

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured out. It seems like it's usual php syntax inside CDATA

```
    <![CDATA[<?php if (isset($this->data['description_new'])) { echo '<div class="content"><h2>Testimonials</h2><div class="box-testimonial">' . $description_new . '</div></div>'; } else { echo ' '; }?>]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

vQmod simply allows you to insert code just like you would normally into a file, but without actually touching the file contents. So yes using an if statement just like you have is fine. Also, one thing I would point out is you should use as little content as you can for the search portion, that's unique. So for your above code

```
echo $description;
```

should be enough to match. It also makes it less likely to break should you use other mods